# ASP.NET MVC - is it possible to choose between multiple authentcation system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c, ws-federation

We have a ASP.NET MVC + Angular SPA stored in the location in Azure (same AppService).
Actually, when we go to the AppService URL (e.g. myapp.customazure.com) it triggers the WsFederation authentication redirecting to the partner website (external provider). After login successfully, our Home.cshtml can run which is typically our Angular (we're rendering Angular javascript files in there).

Our Home.cshtml looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MyApp.Web</title>
    <base href="/">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" />
    <link type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    @Styles.Render("~/styles")
</head>
<body>
    <app-root><div class="spinner"></div></app-root>
    @Scripts.Render("~/runtime")
    @Scripts.Render("~/polyfills")
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts")
    @Scripts.Render("~/main")
</body>
</html>
```

The WsFederation configuration is present in Web.config such as:

```
  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

and of course

```
  <!-- Replaced during Azure DevOps Release-->
  <system.webServer>
  </system.webServer>

  <!-- Replaced during Azure DevOps Release-->
  <system.identityModel>
  </system.identityModel>

  <!-- Replaced during Azure DevOps Release-->
  <system.identityModel.services>
  </system.identityModel.services>
```

What we'd like to achieve is to add the possibility to authenticate using another option (Azure AD B2C). Then in the end there would a new view .cshtml giving two buttons to let user choose between 2 authentications methods:

- Connect with WsFederation as usual
- Connect with Azure AD B2C (new option)

Is it feasible to achieve this kind of thing ? thank you again for your help !

Comment: Instead of declarative configuration, switch to code. Take a look at one of my old tutorials here https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/11/simplest-saml11-federated-authentication.html

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Comment: we'll have to PoC the solution (about authenticating with WsFederation without web.config). But yes it can help us ;) it's just unfortunate that there are not a lot of sample codes. Thanks for your help for both of you :)

Comment: Check out my updated answer, added one more link that can be helpful.

Comment: Thank you singhh-msft, i'll look forward to it when i'll be done with the existing system (WsFederation). I'm experimenting two things:
- 1. convert the whole code from NET4.6 to NETCore
- 2. keep NETFramework but trying to launch authentication from Controller (after click on 'LogIn' button

For the second point, i don't know if OWIN is the solution (everything i found on internet talks about OWIN but I don't know what that is exactly and if it's really required since I don't have it in actual code)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible. As you said, first page will have two buttons for WsFederation and B2C.

Now, you have to redirect your users to your controller action methods based on the button they press.

For **B2C setup in MVC**, you can refer [Quickstart: Set up sign in for an ASP.NET application using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/quickstart-web-app-dotnet).

Further, check out [Integrating a web app with Azure AD using WS-Federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation/) if it suits your requirement.